# ftp port forwarding (i've tried a bunch of solutions)

Tags: port-forwarding, ftp

ASUS router page says

When you set 20:21 as your FTP server's port range for your WAN setup, then your FTP server would be in conflict with TUF-AX3000 V2's native FTP server.
Virtual Server / Port Forwarding FAQ

I'm getting Error: Connection Timed Out
on Filezilla through WAN
but not through LAN, is working

i enabled passive mode, port forwarded, tried other port
i forwarded the passive range and the listening port or whatever

not sure what else to try
i've tried looking for a solution

Comment: Do you know that your traffic is reaching the server over WAN? What is your WAN config? Also, do not just tell us you've tried things: list each thing you've tried so we know what not to suggest, and we also know what you've learned trying those things.

Comment: This sounds like NAT hairpinning not being supported (which many consumer routers don't). this means, when you are inside the network, and you try to connect to a port using the WAN IP address, the traffic is sent to the internet, and then immediately being returned to the router. The router does not expect it, and ignores it, resulting in a timeout. The only way to truly test the ftp server is by connecting from outside the network to it. Eg, using your mobile phone with wifi turned off and only data, or an online port tester, or a friend connecting from their location.

Comment: @LPChip i tried the test FTP website and it waited timed out. Really i just got a brand new router and install Tomato firmware and it can't port forward an FTP? Tomato without the GUI...apparently this model doesn't have the full build. I have another router with DD-WRT but that only does wireless G or N or something.

Comment: @music2myear i tried changing the ports, forwarding them, not sure if i set up Passive correctly. I kept trying and it's working in LAN. i meant i've been reading more tutorials and problem solving but it's mostly all the same thing. there was some on Superuser said something about DMZ.

Comment: did you see what i mentioned about the ASUS router page mentions the FAQ and that it would conflict on port 20/21. But hopefully that's not the case since i've tried forwarding it to a different port or even changing the port locally.

Comment: Does your ISP allow you to get into your network from outside? Many consumer ISPs don't, and you need to go through some hoops to make that work. Being able to determine whether the issue is your server or the upstream network configuration (or limitations) is important. NOTE: Please add any additional information to the question itself, to make the question more clear and complete.

Comment: If you change the port to something other than 21, an FTP tester would also need to have the other port specified. Did the FTP tester allow you to specify the other port?

Comment: Also, did you rule out other connection problems? Such as firewall blocking the incoming connection?

Comment: @music2myear I called my ISP and they said there's a fee for a static IP and suggested i could try my old router, but that if it still has trouble i could pay a bit extra and it should work. I tried the old router and no luck.

Comment: is there another way to get FTP or similar protocol without port forwarding?

Comment: @lpchip yes i already checked all that and it's clear. i've port forwarded before on previous machines and the firewall is set to Allow ftp and it's working locally.

Comment: ok calling my ISP and i got a static IP now they said should fix it. says it can't resolve the host. i plugged the computer directly to the modem now. now says connection timed out. still on the phone with them.

Comment: no luck so far. they suggested asking Filezilla support but that website only allows paid domain email addresses to register.

Comment: A relevant aside: There are more trustworthy FTP tools than FileZilla, which has been caught packaging malware in the past. Have you confirmed the modem has the static IP on its WAN port? Are you able to successfully reach that from outside your network? Are ports forwarded on your modem AND your router?

Comment: Also, there's a lot of questions on this site about accessing internal resources from external connections. Here's one: https://superuser.com/questions/476652/setting-up-a-server-at-home-with-ports-21-and-80 and here's a search I tried https://superuser.com/search?q=internal+ftp+server+static+public+ip

Comment: @music2myear could you please recommend a better FTP server or i can find one. or a different protocol. Maybe a webserver. I got Static IP as of today and have talked to technical support and plugged the computer directly to the modem and configured the IPv4 on that as well again for the static IP. The ISP phone call, they told me it seems all the ports are open and should be fine.

Comment: yes i've read and done the steps on these pages. i've been trying to troubleshoot the router and modem, unplugged them, etc. i get different errors on the FTP test website when i do connect directly to modem.

Comment: the port is confirmed open. the IP is now the new static IP. yes. filezilla listening on (0.0.0.0) port 53000 and (::) on 53000. passive range is 50000-51000 on the new static IP. Trying a separate username/password. Now it works. Huh...i've double checked copy-pasting a complex password. a simple one typed manually worked.

Comment: thanks. maybe i will try SFTPGo or CrushFTP or CerberusFTP or some other one, and try some other protocols. Yep the Static IP seems to fix this, whether that was the problem, but at some point i changed the password before using that Test FTP website or copied it wrong. maybe get a domain name next. thanks!